# LINQ group by hour and add missing integer values

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have written a code like below:

```
var hourlyData = ctx.Transactions
      .GroupBy(x => x.TransactionDate.Value.Hour)
      .Select(pr => new HourlyGraph { 
          Hour = pr.Key,
          Sales = pr.Sum(x => x.QuantitySoldTransaction)
      }).OrderBy(x => x.Hour).ToList();

hourlyData.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(0, 23).Except(hourlyData.Select(m => m.Hour))
          .Select(i => new HourlyGraph() { Hour = i, Sales =0 }));
```

Basically what I'm trying to do is to group all of my transactions from 0-23 (hours) and then add the missing integer values (hours). Those who miss I'd like to assign value - missing hour(22 lets say and sales 0).

The method above that I wrote gives me completely wrong values...

P.S. I get 22 value in hours multiple times, even though it shouldn't be there... 22 should only be repeated once (or any other hour value)...

Comment: Please clarify what *completely wrong values* mean

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy I get 22 value in hours multiple times, even though it shouldn't be there... 22 should only be repeated once

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy how can I convert the integer value of hour to represent it as something like this: 15 to appear like string "15:00" in view?

Comment: There is several ways. Simplest one is interpolated string `var s = $"{i}:00";`

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy $"{i}:00" statement can be done directly in razor?

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong. From the looks, `Enumerable.Range(0, 23).Except...` should produce the missing hours.